# Spring/Angular get current user and save post to that user

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security

Sorry, I am back with just one more question. I have am using Spring security and Angular front end. My question is once I log in, how do I save a post to the current user.

Post model:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String title;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String body;

@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", timezone = "America/New_York")
private Date createdAt;

private String pictureUrl;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user")
private User user;
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
         UsernameNotFoundException {

         // Get the user's username
         User currentUser = repository.findByUsername(username);


    // Create a new UserDetails called user and set to user's :
    // username, current users password, user is enabled, account Non expired, creds non expired
    // account non locked,
    UserDetails user = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, currentUser.getPassword(),
            true, true, true, true,
            AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(currentUser.getRole()));


    return user;
}
```

}

Obviously this works fine with the command line runner:

```
Post post1 = new Post("Title", "Some content", date, user1);
```

Angular:

```
addPost() {
    const title = this.eventForm.get('title').value;
    const body = this.eventForm.get('body').value;


    const newTask: Task = {
        post,
        body
    };

    this.data.addPost(newPost).subscribe((res) => {
       console.log(res);
       this.getPost();
    });
}
```

How can I, once logged in, get the actual user object to save the post object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if this is the correct way to do this, but it works at least! Lol...
It works for now anyways, haha.

```
@Autowired
private PostRepository repository;

@Autowired 
UserRepository userRepository;

@PostMapping("/posts")
public void addPost(@RequestBody Post post) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(auth.getName());
    post.setUser(user);
    this.repository.save(post);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A filter should be implemented, so that you have the chance to record each request. In the filter you can get the current info through `SecurityContextHolder`

```
Authentication authentication =
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

if you are using sprint-boot, you can refer here to add a filter:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter

Comment: Thank you for your response! It did help. It pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have a filter, it's just when I try and save it to the user, I get a string back from it. I'm thinking I need to make a custom UserDetails? class User implements UserDetails? Something like that?

Here is my filter:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain 
filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    Authentication authentication = 
    AuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest)request);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

And trying this...

```
@PostMapping("/posts")
public void addPost(@RequestBody Post post) {
    Authentication authentication = 
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
    post.setUser(user);

    this.repository.save(post);
}
```

I get this...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.chad.familyblog.model.User
```

Am I possibly on the right track of just making a custom UserDetails?